# Date/string formatting/types causing sqlite3/pandas to return misformatted results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I am looking to query a dataframe via sql in python and return some dates in the format of YY-MM, however no matter how I try to do so, I never get the right format to arrive.

Here is the existing script.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import os

desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("path")



csv_files = [ 'file1.csv','file2.csv'
]

dataframes =[]

for file in csv_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0)

    dataframes.append(df)


merged_df = pd.concat(dataframes)

#Convert Date string to datetime
merged_df['Date_alternate'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['Date'])
print(merged_df['Date']) #prints formatted as MM/DD/YYYY, dtype: object
print("Break")
print(merged_df['Date_alternate']) #prints formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, dtype: datetime64[ns]

db_file= "path"

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
merged_df.to_sql('my_table', conn, index=False)

#column_names = merged_df.columns.tolist()


        
query = "select strftime('%y-%m',my_table.Date), strftime('%Y-%m',my_table.Date_alternate),Date, Date_alternate from my_table limit 500"



query_result = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)

print(query_result)

query_result.to_csv('path', index=False)#, header=column_names)

conn.close()
```

What I would ideally want is either of first two columns in the query to simply return the dates in the format YY-MM, but both of those `strftime` columns return simply "None". Date returns formatted MM/DD/YYYY and Date_alernate returns just a number. Ex:

```
02/19/2021 | 1613624400
02/28/2021 | 1614488400
```

Comment: The right way to do this is to leave these columns as native date/time objects throughout, and then do the formatting with pandas.  Remember that your `'merged_df['Date']` column is just a string.  It's not a date/time type, so Sqlite's `strftime` doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: Having said that, your code works just fine for the `Date_alternate` column.  I get "YYYY-MM" in the resulting dataframe.  That's the way you should handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code demonstrating that your code works just fine if you leave the data as date/time objects:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import os

data = [
    [ 1, '2020-02-02' ],
    [ 2, '2021-03-03' ],
    [ 3, '2023-04-04' ]
]

merged_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['who','Date'] )

merged_df['Date_alternate'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['Date'])

print(merged_df['Date']) #prints formatted as MM/DD/YYYY, dtype: object
print("Break")
print(merged_df['Date_alternate']) #prints formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, dtype: datetime64[ns]

db_file= "path.db"
if os.path.exists(db_file):
    os.remove(db_file)

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
merged_df.to_sql('my_table', conn, index=False)

query = "select strftime('%Y-%m',my_table.Date_alternate) as Other ,Date, Date_alternate from my_table limit 500"

query_result = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)

print(query_result)
```

Output:

```
0    2020-02-02
1    2021-03-03
2    2023-04-04
Name: Date, dtype: object
Break
0   2020-02-02
1   2021-03-03
2   2023-04-04
Name: Date_alternate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
     Other        Date       Date_alternate
0  2020-02  2020-02-02  2020-02-02 00:00:00
1  2021-03  2021-03-03  2021-03-03 00:00:00
2  2023-04  2023-04-04  2023-04-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: I'm sorry but then there must be something else going on, since the code I posted yields the following results:

    `strftime('%Y-%m',my_table.Date) | strftime('%Y-%m',my_table.Date_alternate)|Date|Date_alternate`
0                              None | None | 02/28/2021 |1614488400
1                              None | None | 02/28/2021 | 1614488400
2                              None | None | 02/28/2021 | 1614488400
What could be the problem?

Comment: I can't explain that.  Does my exact code work for you?  What versions (Python, pandas)?

Comment: No, your exact code keeps the same error I am seeing, but with your data. None for the Other, Date as 2020-02-02 and Date_alternate = 1580619600.

Python version = 3.11.5
Pandas version = 2.1.0

Comment: I'm using pandas 1.5.3, but I'm not aware of any date/time changes between them.

Comment: Switching to `strftime('%Y-%m', my_table.Date_alternate, 'unixepoch')` fixed it, but I am not really sure why. Any ideas?